# Why should a fuse be installed in live instead of neutral?

Tags: ac, fuses

**I understand why it should be installed in positive instead of negative side in DC, but this is AC. Direction of current reverses half of the time.**

It is said that installing a fuse in neutral causes a high potential difference between live and the fuse. However, isnt it the same if you install it in live? Since it is AC, the potential difference between the fuse and neutral will be negatively high, which causes equal amount of damage in a ground fault.

Answer (score 6):

If the fuse is on the live side and it blows, only the conductor between supply point and fuse stays live.

If the fuse is on the neutral the the live path is much longer and a short directly to the live sidecan cause a fire even if the neutral side fuse blows.

Answer (score 4):

The neutral and earth are nominally at the same potential.

So if you put the fuse in the neutral, then an alternate path through earth exists that current could flow through even if the fuse opens. That could cause a shock to a user, for example, or excessive current bypassing the (now open) fuse.

Answer (score 1):

> It is said that installing a fuse in neutral causes a high potential difference between live and the fuse.

Whoever said that wasn't being clear. There is always a high potential difference between live and neutral so if the fuse is in the neutral then there must be "a high potential difference between live and the fuse".

> However, isnt it the same if you install it in live? Since it is AC, the potential difference between the fuse and neutral will be negatively high, which causes equal amount of damage in a ground fault.

1. Mains power is AC. It alternates so "negatively high" doesn't make any sense.
2. The neutral wire is "neutralised" by connecting it to earth at the local supply transformer or/and building entrance (depending on local regulations). This means that it should be within a few volts of earth potential during normal operation. (If the neutral current is high then a few volts will be dropped across the length of the cable due to its resistance.)

Consider the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnmLpT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- (a) is normal operation. The load is inside an earthed metal case. F1 is in the live conductor. The metal case is at earth potential as is the neutral conductor.
- (b) An internal fault occurs and the live wire touches the metal case. The earth conductor provides a low resistance path back to the transformer and a high current flows. This blows F2. Note that the voltage on the case will rise somewhat due to the voltage drop on the earth wire caused by the fault current. Once the fuse blows the voltage will fall to zero. This is intended design.
- (c) The fuse is in the neutral conductor. Now the same fault causes the case to go live but there is no fuse protection. You are now relying on some upstream protection and usually the upstream protection will have a higher trip setting so more energy will be dissipated in the fault, etc.
- (d) If a fault occurs between neutral and the case the situation is not considered as dangerous as the neutral and case are bonded to each other. With a "perfect" short circuit between the neutral and case the return current will split between the neutral and earth return wires in inverse proportion to their resistances.

An RCD / GFCI / ELCB fitted to the L and N supply after the Earth connection will detect any imbalance between currents in the L and N and isolate the supply.

> ... which causes equal amount of damage in a ground fault.

It should be clear now that having the fuse in the neutral can cause a much greater fault current than having the fuse in the live.

---

> I understand why it should be installed in positive instead of negative side in DC, ...

On a "negative earth" system, yes. On a positive earth system the opposite would be true.

> ... but this is AC. Direction of current reverses half of the time.

Yes, but one conductor has zero potential.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to blow the fuse: -

- Live fault to neutral
- Live fault to ground

So, putting the fuse in neutral only solves one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

> It is said that installing a fuse in neutral causes a high potential
>   difference between live and the fuse. However, isnt it the same if you
>   install it in live? Since it is AC, the potential difference between
>   the fuse and neutral will be negatively high, which causes equal
>   amount of damage in a ground fault.

What you might not realize is this: in mains wall power, the neutral line is electrically bonded to planet Earth at your location. A metal rod (usually copper) is driven into the Earth at your location, and the mains power neutral line is electrically bonded to that metal rod.  Therefore, the mains power neutral line is at the same voltage potential as the Earth potential at your location on planet Earth.

Because the neutral line is at the same voltage potential as your local Earth potential, the risk of electric shock is less if you happen to touch the neutral line while you are standing on the Earth. *(NB: There is still a non-zero risk of electric shock if you come into contact with the neutral line, so don't imagine that contacting the neutral line is completely safe; it isn't.)*

On the other hand, the sinusoidal AC voltage on the "hot" line varies both positive and negative relative to (i.e., referenced to) the constant Earth potential on the neutral line.

So, the neutral line is your "zero" voltage reference potential, and the "hot" line has the 120 VRMS AC voltage relative to (referenced to) the neutral potential.

For optimal safety, then, one wants to eliminate the 120 VRMS voltage from the system when the fuse blows, leaving only the neutral Earth potential which is less hazardous.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZQgTH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*